# XSL Stylesheet how to use "and / or" in replace

Tags: if-statement, xslt, stylesheet

On the variable "urgent", I have put a "replace" on it, so if the string in the variable are "Urgent - 2 arbejdsdage" its changes it to "YES". But if the string are "Overnight" it must also changes it to "YES", can i put a "or" in the style, or must I use "xsl:if" How can i do it ?

```
<variable name="urgent">
    <xsl:variable name ="urgent" select="OrderCustomReferences/CustomReference/ReferenceValue"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($urgent, 'Urgent - 2 arbejdsdage', 'Yes')"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</variable>
```

Comment: do a double replace `replace(replace($urgent, 'Urgent - 2 arbejdsdage', 'Yes'), 'Overnight', 'Yes')`

Comment: If the whole string will be either "Urgent - 2 arbejdsdage" or "Overnight" (as opposed to just a part of the string", then you could do this instead: `<xsl:value-of select="if ($urgent = ('Urgent - 2 arbejdsdage', 'Overnight')) then 'Yes' else $urgent"/>`

Comment: THANKS, its works. that was easy, when  you know it. :-D